# How to calculate total distance covered by a sensor from its set of locations which are 3D points?

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I am using Qt GUI to track the motion of a sensor. The mainwindow.cpp file is:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "ATC3DG.h"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "QTimer"
#include "qtimer.h"
#include "math.h"

double square(double x)
{
    return x*x;
}


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_start_clicked()
{
    points.clear();   //points is a global std::vector<cv::Point3> declared in mainwindow.h
    errorCode = InitializeBIRDSystem();
    errorCode = GetBIRDSystemConfiguration(&ATC3DG.m_config);
    id = 0;
    errorCode = SetSystemParameter(SELECT_TRANSMITTER, &id, sizeof(id));
    EM_time = new QTimer(this);
    connect(EM_time, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(showValues()));
    EM_time->start();
}

void MainWindow::showValues()
{
    EM_time->stop();
    pRecord = &record;
    {
        sensorID = 0;
        {
            errorCode = GetAsynchronousRecord(sensorID, pRecord, sizeof(record));
            unsigned int status = GetSensorStatus(sensorID);
            if ( status == VALID_STATUS )
            {
                points.push_back(cv::Point3f(record.x, record.y, record.z));
                QString str;
                str.sprintf("%f, %f, %f",record.x, record.y, record.z );
                this->ui->label->setText(str);
            }
        }
    }
    EM_time->start();
}

void MainWindow::on_stop_clicked()
{
    EM_time->stop();
    double sum = 0;
    double dist;
    QString str;

    for (int i=0; i<points.size()-1; i++)
    {
       dist = sqrt(square(points[i].x - points[i+1].x) + square(points[i].y - points[i+1].y) + square(points[i].z - points[i+1].z));
       sum = sum+dist;
    }
    str.sprintf("%d cm", sum*2.54);
    this->ui->distance->setText(str);
}
```

ATC3DG.h is the header file of the sensor. record.x, record.y, record.z gives the 3D location of x, y and z location of the sensor in *inches*. Basically what I am doing is, when I click the **start** button, the sensor is switched on and the QTimer starts with its signal emitted during timeouts and the **showvalues()** function will start to execute. This function displays the position of the sensor in **label** of the Qt GUI. During this loop, **points** will be filled with all the position values of the sensor.

The **stop** button stops the timer and calculates the distance using all the points containing in the **points** vector. This is done using:

```
double sum=0;
double dist;
for (int i=0; i<points.size()-1; i++)
    {
       dist = sqrt(square(points[i].x - points[i+1].x) + square((int)points[i].y - (int)points[i+1].y) + square(points[i].z - points[i+1].z));
       sum = sum+dist;
    }
```

The **sum** is giving me totally weird values. For example, when the sensor has moved only about 5 or 6 inches, it is showing values in the range of 100s and like that.

My mainwindow.h file is:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "ATC3DG.h"
#include "QTimer"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class CSystem
{
public:
    SYSTEM_CONFIGURATION m_config;
};
class CSensor
{
public: SENSOR_CONFIGURATION m_config;
};
class CXmtr
{
public: TRANSMITTER_CONFIGURATION m_config;
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();


public slots:
    void on_start_clicked();
    void showValues();
    void on_stop_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
private:
    DOUBLE_POSITION_ANGLES_RECORD record, *pRecord;
    CSystem ATC3DG;
    CSensor *pSensor;
    CXmtr *pXmtr;
    int errorCode;
    int sensorID;
    int i;
    short id;
    QTimer *EM_time;
    std::vector<cv::Point3f> points;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: It would be a good start to check all those `errorCode`s for errors.

Comment: I have checked it already. There are no errors.

Answer (score 1):

issues I can see in your code:

1. overuse of braces (they do nothing) - this looks strange and may led to errors
2. `GetAsynchronousRecord` suggest asynchronous action and you are using value immediately! I don't known this library but this looks suspicious.
3. start and stop timer in same method.
4. you are calculating sum of distances from probably very noisy data. This means that when you do not move sensor over a time you are calculating sum of noise and as a result you have large distance when sensor is not moved at all. You have to filter data before calculating such distance (the easiest is low pass filter).